# Add or Clear localStorage on button click and show the value in html

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

I have a code that uses localStorage and javascript. I tried to add more slots, like slot1, slot2, slot3 up to 5. I just copy and paste then change the variable names like like slot1, slot2, slot3 up to 5. But it won't work. Help will be appreciated so much.

Javascript:

```
var slot = localStorage.getItem("slot");

if (slot == null) {
    slot = 10;
}

document.getElementById("slot").innerText = slot;

function reduceSlot() {
    if (slot >= 1) {
        slot--;
        localStorage.setItem("slot", slot);
        if (slot > 0) {
            document.getElementById('slot').innerText = slot;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('slot').innerText = "FULL";
            document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("button1").onclick = reduceSlot;

function clearLocalStorage() {
    localStorage.clear();
}
```

HTML:

```
<p id="slot">10</p>
<a href="javascript:reduceSlot(1)" id="button1">Deduct</a>
<button onclick="window.localStorage.clear();">Clear All</button>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/K8stQ/3/

Comment: Your `reduceSlot` function seems to missing a parameter. You call it with `reduceSlot(1)`.

Comment: but it won't work when i added `reduceSlot(1)`

Comment: can you help me with this? @Thilo

Comment: if someone had written a post solving this, what do you think the perfect title for that post would be? One that might help you find it in Google? Hold that thought.....then edit the title of your question to match :)

Comment: Updated question title.

Comment: thanks for acceptin my answer.. but my code is incomplete.. the slots won't change to "FULL" because of ( >= 1).. but i guess you can fix that.. :)

Comment: @yeah it not really important about the "FULL" thing, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure but. is this what you want to do?? [working demo](http://jsbin.com/IGiLUKO/3/)

i changed your code a bit.. you can change it into your liking later..

```
 <span id="slot0">10</span><input type="button" value="Deduct" onclick="(function(){reduceSlot(0)})()" ><br>

      <span id="slot1">10</span><input type="button" value="Deduct" onclick="(function(){reduceSlot(1)})()" ><br>

      <span id="slot2">10</span><input type="button" value="Deduct" onclick="(function(){reduceSlot(2)})()" ><br>

      <span id="slot3">10</span><input type="button" value="Deduct" onclick="(function(){reduceSlot(3)})()" ><br>

      <span id="slot4">10</span><input type="button" value="Deduct" onclick="(function(){reduceSlot(4)})()" ><br>


  <p>
  <button onclick="clearAll()">Clear All</button>
    </p>
```

and for the js...

```
ls = localStorage.getItem("slots") ;
if(!ls) {    localStorage.setItem("slots", "10,10,10,10,10");  
}

var slots = localStorage.getItem("slots").split(',').map(Number);

window.onload = updateSlots;

  function updateSlots() {  for(var i=0;i<slots.length;i++) {
document.getElementById('slot' + i ).innerHTML = slots[i] ;
}}



var  reduceSlot = function(slotId) {
  console.log(slots[slotId]) ;
  if(slots[slotId] >= 1) {
    slots[slotId]--; localStorage.setItem("slots",slots); 
     document.getElementById('slot' + slotId).innerHTML = slots[slotId];
  }


    else {      document.getElementById('slot'+slotId).innerText = "FULL";

        }
    };

function clearAll() {
  window.localStorage.clear();
  slots = [10,10,10,10,10];
  updateSlots();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

***Script***

```
window.ready = function() {
    checkStorage();
}

function checkStorage() {
    var slot = localStorage.getItem("slot");
    if (slot == null) {
       slot = 10;
    }
    document.getElementById("slot").innerHTML = slot;
}


function reduceSlot() {
    var slot = localStorage.getItem("slot");
    if (slot == null) {
       slot = 10;
    }
    if (slot >= 1) {
        slot--;
        localStorage.setItem("slot", slot);
        if (slot > 0) {
            document.getElementById('slot').innerHTML = slot;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('slot').innerHTML = "FULL";
            document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}

document.getElementById("button1").onclick = reduceSlot;
document.getElementById("clear").onclick = clear_me;

function clear_me() {
    localStorage.clear();
    checkStorage();
}
```

***HTML***

```
<p id="slot">10</p>
<a href="javascript:void(null)" id="button1">Deduct</a>

<button id="clear">Clear All</button>
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HVJ79/1/)***